# Angular 2 AOT compiler with definetly typed support

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I got a compiler error using angular 2 aot compile when I tries to use an external javascript file with a definetly typed interface when I run a

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

My tsconfig-aot.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },

  "files": [
    "tmp/app/app.module.ts",
    "tmp/app/main.ts"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "tmp/aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```

Error message:

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
Error at (...) public/tmp/app/services/service-messaging-stomp.ts:77:26: Cannot find name 'StompClient'.
Error at (...) public/tmp/app/services/service-messaging-stomp.ts:79:39: Cannot find name 'StompSubscription'.
...
```

service-messaging-stomp.ts file references the stomp.d.ts:

```
"use strict";

/// <reference path="./stomp.d.ts"/>
```

from line 77 to 79:

```
private stompClient: StompClient;
private path: string;
private uiDeviceEventSubsription: StompSubscription = null;
```

stomp.d.ts is in the same directory, but it seems that it not uses this file, because it not recognizes the StompClient and StompSubscription types.

Can anybody tell me how can I use definetly typed references with angular AOT compilation? (It works with JIT compilation)

My stomp.d.ts file:

```
// Type definitions for Stomp
// Project: https://stomp.github.io/
// Definitions by: Daniel Kis <https://github.com/kisdaniel>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

interface StompArguments {
    port: number;
    host: string;
    debug: boolean;
    login: string;
    passcode: string;
}

interface StompSendArguments {
    destination?: string;
    body?: string;
    persistent?: string;
    transaction?: string;
    priority?: number;
}

interface StompHeaders {
    [key: string]: string;
    login?: string;
    passcode?: string;
}
interface StompTransaction {
    id: string;
    commit(): void;
    abort(): void;
}
interface StompErrorHeader {
    message: string;
}

interface StompError {
    headers: StompErrorHeader;
}

interface StompStatic {
    over(socket: SockJS): StompClient;
    overTCP(host: string, port: number): StompClient;
    overWS(url: string): StompClient;
    client(url: string): StompClient;
}

interface StompMessage {
    body: string;
}

interface StompSubscribeHeaders {
    [key: string]: string;
    id: string;
    ack: string;
}

interface StompSubscription {
    unsubscibe(): void;
}

interface Heartbeat {
    outgoing: number;
    incoming: number;
}

interface StompClient {
    constructor(args: StompArguments): void;
    connect(login: string, passcode: string, connectCallback: () => (void)): void;
    connect(login: string, passcode: string, connectCallback: () => (void), errorCallback: (error: StompError) => (void)): void;
    connect(login: string, passcode: string, connectCallback: () => (void), errorCallback: () => (void), host: string): void;

    connect(headers: StompHeaders, callback: (frame: string) => (void)): void;
    connect(headers: StompHeaders, callback: (frame: string) => (void), errorCallBack: () => (void)): void;
    on(event: string, callback: (param: any) => (void)): void;

    subscribe(queue: string, callback: (message: StompMessage) => (void), headers: StompSubscribeHeaders): StompSubscription;
    subscribe(queue: string, callback: (message: StompMessage) => (void)): StompSubscription;

    send(params: StompSendArguments): void;
    send(path: string, params: StompSendArguments): void;
    send(path: string, params: StompSendArguments, message: string): void;
    begin(): StompTransaction;
    disconnect(): void;

    heartbeat: Heartbeat;
}

declare var Stomp: StompStatic;
```